# Need to print the content of a textbox using JavaScript, but it keeps duplicating each entry

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to take websites that are submitted in the form and print them onto the page.  It is working, however it keeps printing the last entry plus the new entry every time.  Sorry if it is messy, I am still learning!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="favourites.js"></script>
  <link href="part3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous"      rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div id ="back">
<a class="homebutton" href="index.html">Home</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
<h1 style ="text-align:center">Favourite Website Organizer</h2>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<h2>Please Enter Your Favourite Website, then click enter:</h2>

<br>
<form id="website" style = "text-align:center">
<input type="text" maxlength="25" id="webSite" placeholder=www.example.com      style="text-align:center">

<button class="button" value="Enter" onclick="storeData();return false">     <span>Enter</span></button>
</form>
<h3>This is a list of your favourite sites</h3>
<span id = "result"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript

```
  var webAddress=[];



 function storeData() {
  var address;

  var website;
  var thisAddress;
  var i=0;
  var outmessage="";
  website=document.getElementById("webSite").value;

  webAddress.push(website);
  for(i=0; i< webAddress.length;i++)
     {
       outmessage+=outmessage+ "<a target=\"_blank\"  href=http://"+webAddress[i]+">"+webAddress[i]+"</a>"+"<br>";
    }
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=outmessage;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
outmessage += outmessage + "<a target=\"_blank\" ..."
```

...to this:

```
outmessage += "<a target=\"_blank\" ..."
```

Given two variables `x` and `y`, `x += y` is already equivalent to `x = x + y`. No need to add `x` again!

```js
var webAddress = [];

function storeData() {
  var address;
  var thisAddress;
  var i = 0;
  var outmessage = "";
  var website = document.getElementById("webSite").value;

  webAddress.push(website);
  for (i = 0; i < webAddress.length; i++) {
    outmessage += "<a target=\"_blank\"  href=http://" + webAddress[i] + ">" + webAddress[i] + "</a><br>";
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = outmessage;

}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="favourites.js"></script>
  <link href="part3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous" rel="stylesheet">

  <body>
    <div id="back">
      <a class="homebutton" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <h1 style="text-align:center">Favourite Website Organizer</h1>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <br>
      <h2>Please Enter Your Favourite Website, then click enter:</h2>

      <br>
      <form id="website" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" maxlength="25" id="webSite" placeholder=www.example.com style="text-align:center">

        <button class="button" value="Enter" onclick="storeData();return false">     <span>Enter</span></button>
      </form>
      <h3>This is a list of your favourite sites</h3>
      <span id="result"></span>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a few people look at it and not pick that up...so silly.